# raphael js crop image

Tags: raphael

i have this problem with loading image with Raphael JS.
i am doing this to load a image:

```
paper.image("images/image.png", 0, 0, 488, 300);
```

and it is ok, but i would like to load this image but to crop it 29px on the right, i have tried like this:

```
paper.image("images/image.png", 0, 0, (488-29), 300);
```

but i get i scaled.

i have tried to find any information on http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html but with no success, also using .attr({"width", (488-29}) doesn't give me result i want

how can i get this done?

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to crop an image you have to use [**clip-rect**](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr)(scroll just a little bit down to "possible parameters"; clip-rect is the second one)

```
var theImage = paper.image("image.png", xPosition, yPosition, imageWidth, imageHeight);
theImage.attr({"clip-rect":"0 0 100 150"});
```

Like this you will show only the top left part of the image with 100 pixels width and 150 pixels height.

Comment: thanks for the solution. i need to read better svg documentation. is it possible to crop image to show for example top-right part?

Comment: the attributes for clip-rect are x, y, width, height, so yes, you can crop any part of the image