# How to clip content using a rect element in raphaeljs?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

How a `rect` element can be used for clipping the content using rapaheljs ? I achieved this by creating the elements manually. The markup I created is given below and now I want to do this with raphaeljs.

```
<clipPath id="clipper">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="160" width="250"/>
</clipPath> 
<g clip-path="url(#clipper)">
...
...
</g>
```

Or is there any other method using rapaheljs for creating a clipping rectangle like this ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [raphael js crop image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948866/raphael-js-crop-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Raphaël this is how:

```
elm.attr({clip-rect: "0 0 160 160"})
```

...where elm is the <g> element in your example.